# Reading data from files of varying length and varying columns

Tags: python-2.7

I've been reading stackoverflow questions all morning, trying different approaches with no headway.

I'm trying to automate the process of reading data from 318 qdp files for plotting onto a graph (plus a few other things). The reason I'm doing this and not using qdp is because it's not helpful for what I'm trying to do.

The qdp file is just like any other .txt file, except with hidden characters of \n after each line and \t between each data entry so reading from it in a pythonic way should be straightforward. However the file format is giving me a headache.

A typical file has the following format:

```
Header - 8 Lines
space
qdp code line       
datatype header      \ Data Group 
data column header   /     1
data - 6 columns    /
qdp code line       
datatype header      \ Data Group
data column header   /     2
data - 6 columns    /
```

This seems straightforward enough, however each file has varying numbers of data groups (between 1 and 3), of which only 1 I want to extract. So sometimes the data I want is the first group, sometimes it's the second and sometimes there isn't a data group after the data I want and thus the extra qdp code line isn't there.

Each line (except data) has varying amount of columns, so np.genfromtxt doesn't work. I've tried telling it to ignore every line till it finds the specific datatype header which heads the data I want and then extract from there but I can't seem to figure out how to do that. I've tried reading the file, assigning each line an index and then going back to find the index of the datatype header and going from there but with no success either.

Like my previous questions its seems like such a trivial issue, and yet I can't figure it out.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: You need to figure out something unique about the data group you want to extract, some defining characteristics that tell you "yes, this is the group" and then basically match on that. Otherwise there's nothing much you can do there I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

So after more reading and trying all sorts of solutions, I've come up with a rather inelegant solution.

```
with open(file, "r") as f:
    index = 0
    data_start = 0
    data_end = 0
    EOF = 0

    for line in f:
         temp = line.strip()
         datatemp.append(temp)

         if line.strip() == "datatype header":
             index += 1
             data_start = index + 2 

         elif line.strip() == "next datatype header":
             index += 1
             data_end = index - 3 

         else:
             index += 1

    if f.readline() = "":
        EOF = index

if data_end == 0:
    data_end = EOF
```

Thus in the case when there is a data group after the one I want to extract, it uses that groups header to point back to end of data to be extracted, and when the data group I want to extract is the last group in the file it uses the EOF marker to point back.

After this I then split datatemp into 6 columns, assigning each to a list. Finally I can then manipulate the data I wanted and the program runs through all 318 files yey!